# Can Firefox use the Windows certificate store?

Tags: windows, firefox, client-certificate

How can I get Firefox to use the Windows certificate store to look for client certificates?

Use case: Web authentication with a client certificate that is stored in the Windows certificate store and secured with [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module). The certificate is visible there and automatically unlocked (by PIN) when accessed via the certificate store. The private key cannot be exported (for non-administrators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How can I get Firefox to use the Windows certificate store to look for client certificates?**

It does not appear that this is possible according to [**Wiki Mozilla**](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:AddRootToFirefox). This article does talk about how to get the CA's into Firefox though so it may be worth reading entirely. I also posted another article at the bottom with potential workaround, etc.

[**Installing Certificates Into Firefox**](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:AddRootToFirefox)

> There are lots of organizations that use their own certificate
>   authority to issue certificates for their internal servers. Since
>   **Firefox does not use the Windows certificate store** (bug [432802](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=432802), bug
>   [472113](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=472113)), these have to be manually added into Firefox. This page will
>   cover how to get those CAs into Firefox.

---

- [**Another Article with Potential Workaround Solution**](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1925477)
- [**Double Confirmation**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/893604)

---

### Update

[**Source**](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/SmartCardHSM)

> ### **Using the PKCS#11 module in Firefox and Thunderbird**
>
> After installation of OpenSC you must register the PKCS11 module in
>   Firefox:
>
> 1. Open the Firefox preferences dialog. Choose “Advanced” > “Encryption” > “Security Devices”
> 2. Choose “Load”
> 3. Enter a name for the security module, such as “OpenSC”
> 4. Choose “Browse…” to find the location of the PKCS11 module on your local computer (Usually c:\WINDOWS\System32\opensc-pkcs11.dll or
>      /usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so)

**Other Potential Resources**

- [**Resource Potential**](http://www.secure-endpoints.com/kcacred/instkpkcs11.html)
- [**Reference Resource Only**](http://www.charismathics.com/fileadmin/files/pdf/manuals/How_to_configure_iEnigma_for_Mozilla_Thunderbird.pdf)

---

### Further Clarification

If you're wondering where to find the `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` setting, form the **Firefox** address bar, you can type in `About:Config`, and then press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd>.

> **Important:** If you get the warning that "***`This might void your warranty`***"
>   you will need to select the ***`I accept the risk`*** ([image]) option.

In the **Search** field, type in *"security"* and press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> to see the setting and attributes from there.

[image]

Comment: The problem are not CA's, but client certificates. These come from SmartCards or Virtual SmartCards but the middlewareallows to treat them as standard client certificates that are stored in the Windows Certificate Store.

You can add PKCS#11 cryptography modules in Firefox, but which dll do In have to chosse here? If there is one?

Comment: @FragmentationNeeded I added an update section to my answer, take a look over it and its links and let me know if that helps any.

Comment: Installing OpenSC in Firefox works, but it seems not to support a TPM-secured VirtualSmartcard. And I don't have a glue which dll to choose or if M$ even provides a library fort hat. Thanks, in any case!

Comment: @FragmentationNeeded I would think it's be `opensc-pkcs11.dll` as long as your smart card is supported by OpenSC for authentication, signing
and decryption. Let me know if they helps you get it to work as expected or not.

Comment: That first link to the Wiki Mozilla article says to set 'security.enterprise_roots.enabled' but I cannot find this setting anywhere

Comment: @riqitang Bit late, but for anyone else that might stumble on this, that setting is in "about:config". http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config

Comment: Recent changes in Firefox (version 68) allows one to configure it in such a way that the entreprise roots will be automatically enabled after a TLS handshake error is encountered: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-disable-enterprise-roots-preference  This behaviour is enabled by default :-( You have another new preference item (`security.certerrors.mitm.auto_enable_enterprise_roots`)  to disable the automated enabling of entreprise roots after TLS errors.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is no longer accurate.

[As of v90, Firefox will use client certificates available to the OS by default](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/07/28/making-client-certificates-available-by-default-in-firefox-90/).  If your certs work from other browsers that integrate with MSCAPI (anything Chromium-based), they should now work from Firefox as well.